# Assigning correct permissions on a shared web server

Tags: apache-2.2, file-permissions, user-permissions

I have created a centos instance on digital ocean hosting multiple websites by setting up virtual host, all is working fine, however assigning correct directory permission for each website is bugging me and i could not find any relevant answer by searching, hence hoping someone here could lend me a helping hand, let me elaborate.

For the sake of explanation lets assume i am hosting a.com and b.com on my web server, i also created 2 users which is "user_a" and "user_b" and here is my directory structure for hosting the files

```
Directory #1 : /var/www/a.com/public_html
Directory #2 : /var/www/b.com/public_html
```

**Directory#1** is assigned `user_a by` running the following command

```
sudo chown -R user_a:user_a /var/www/a.com/public_html
```

**Directory#2** is assigned `user_b` by running the following command

```
sudo chown -R user_b:user_b /var/www/b.com/public_html
```

My issue is that Apache/PHP is running under the user `www` and when it tries uploading file using PHP it throws permission error, O assume it is because project directory is assigned a different user and Apache is running under different user (please correct me if i am wrong).

The easiest work-around is to reassign www user to project directory, however i am not sure if it is a security flaw, or i would like to know how to go with the user permission in such situation?

Thanks

Comment: This is already answered, http://serverfault.com/questions/128886/apache-suexec-php-suphp

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo chown -R user_a:www /var/www/a.com/public_html
```

Then:

```
chmod 0775 -R /var/www/a.com/public_html
```